# How to store coordinates to act like a hexagon-esque structure?

Tags: java, data-structures, coordinates, storage, converters

I realize that many questions about pixels and hexagons have been asked, but I'm struggling to understand a certain aspect of it. Also, I'm not sure how much of a difference it'll make, but I am working in Java.

Starting off with my comprehension of the matter, I understand a Cartesian grid could be stored in a 2d array so that coordinates on the board are each an entry in the 2d array. But, I want to use a hexagonal sort of grid for a better game grid, like described on Amit's page http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/.

I understand the concept after the hexagonal grid has been created (using x, y, z to get neighbors), but am struggling to store my coordinates. Previously, each coordinate had corresponded to an entry in the 2d array (cartesian). Now, I'm not sure how to make it correspond to get a hexagonal relationship between the coordinates.

Following the guide, I tried to offset the coordinates every other row (specifically trying the even row offset example from the link), like so:

[image]

In this, the top is the coordinates and the bottom is the visual representation of the array (blank spaces are entries with sentinels to 'skip' over, and 1s are the entries that correspond to the coordinates).

So, the neighbors of each coordinate are { {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {0, 2}, {0, -2} }. However, I don't think this is properly done? I thought of other ways to implement a hexagonal grid, which were to use a doubly linked list sort of structure and start off from the middle and relate the coordinates as 'nodes', or to hard code a map (which is sort of impossible because I plan for a large map). But, I'd rather stick with the offset idea because it's easier to use.

I think my problem is that each other row should be shifted by 1/2, but I give it 'holes' (sentinel entries). Maybe I'm supposed to convert coordinates to a hexagon using the geometry of hexagons. but I don't understand how I can use those individual hexagons when I want to path find unless they were stored in some data structure. Any code or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        0   1   2   3   4   5
      0   1   2   3   4   5
    0   1   2   3   4   5
  0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

If you don't mind your map having somewhat of a diamond shape, you can neatly fit a set of hexagons into a 2-d array.  The math will be consistent for travelling between nodes--

(E/W change x, NE/SW change y, NW/SE change both).

Basically, you're using the coordinate mapping as a reference.  You don't need to actually construct your map onto a two dimensional array.  Rather, you use the coordinate mapping to simplify your relationships.

For example, you could map coordinates into a hashmap like

```
map.put("0,2", new Tile(0,2,"Green"));
map.put("0,3", new Tile(0,3,"Yellow"));
map.put("0,4", new Tile(0,4,"Green"));
map.put("0,5", new Tile(0,5,"Green"));
map.put("1,2", new Tile(1,2,"Blue"));
map.put("1,3", new Tile(1,3,"Red"));
map.put("1,4", new Tile(1,4,"Orange"));
map.put("2,1", new Tile(2,1,"Orange"));
```

For any given tile, you could answer whether any given direction is available, and retrieve the tile in that direction in O(1) time by referencing the HashMap.  Your nodes (e.g. Tile objects) wouldn't need any references to neighboring nodes.  Your coordinate system would take care of that.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you would initialize the 2d array? Like with a double for loop, how do you know how much space to leave in the first row before assigning a value?

Comment: That depends on the shape of your map.  If it's diamond-shaped as shown, you wouldn't need to leave any spaces blank.  If you wanted a squashed hexagonal shape, you could leave off (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (3,5), (4,4), (4,5).  Your for loop could just traverse the whole map and only address non-null values.

Comment: My map is actually the entirety of a rectangular window, approximately 720 x 720 nodes (coordinates stored in each node). Is there some way I can calculate which parts on the left and right to leave out?

Comment: It costs half an offset per row, so if you wanted to stay zero-based in your array, your lower left corner (depending on how you define x and y) would start at 359.  Keep in mind, the "array" is just a way of mapping coordinates-- you wouldn't necessarily need to construct it.  Your database of nodes could live in a hashmap, for example.

Comment: So for a nxn board, the offset is n/2 -1, and for future purpose what would be the offset of a nxp board? Eg a 1080 x 720 or a 600 x 800?

Comment: It would be p/2-1.  Of course, if you're not trying to actually store it in an array, then you could offset it however you want, or allow it to go negative. 
 The math for traversing in any direction or determining neighbors will remain the same.